# Xamarin Forms Dropdown Menu

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and I was wondering if it is possible in Xamarin Forms to create a menu similar to this:

[image: a menu similar to this] .

Comment: You should explain a bit what you have tried. Looks like something not directly available, you have to construct the menu yourself. But that should be fairly easy, just open the submenu at correct position, when user clicks the main menu item.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to do a SlideOver menu which I would suggest using [SlideOverKit](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit)

They support some nice menu options which you can adapt with and is easily implementable by using their nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. I recommend you have a look at [Custom renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/). They enable you to do whatever the executing platform is capable of. Note that depending on what you need there may be plenty of platform knowledge that is needed.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look to Custom renderers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [SyncFusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin) component called DataGrid. SyncFusion has many great components for Xamarin forms. They also have a community license were you can get all components for free if you are qualified.

[image: SyncFusion DataGrid]

you can use this list in your custom master detail or menu component.